# Error While trying to run the project: could not load file or assembly 'Windowsformapplication1' or one of its dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, .net-assembly

**Scenario:** I have windows form application, it was working fine before two days but after last two days it is giving me error:

> Error While trying to run the project: could not load file or assembly
>   'Windows form application 1' or one of its dependencies

I have tried two days to find solutions but all in vain.

Could any body please help me or suggest me some suggestions.

Comment: Where did the spaces in the name come from?  The boilerplate name for a winforms app is WindowsFormsApplication1.  If you rename it then do pick a name without spaces to avoid accidents.  Look at the Error window to ensure that the project built correctly.

Comment: It looks like one of the assemblies you are referencing is missing. If you've spent two days chasing this already, it may be faster to tart from scratch, and move the code into a new project, trying to see that your program remains runnable after each modification that you make.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your project's name doesn't have an apostrophe, as they can cause errors.

Comment: This worked for me.  My assembly name had an apostrophe; removing it compiled the application.

Answer (score 5):

I have found three simple steps:

GO TO START ---> RUN

1. Type `prefetch` and delete all files
2. Type `recent` and delete all files
3. Type `%temp%` and delete all files

Answer (score 2):

Probably, one of designed component thrown unhandled exception during initialization of events. 
Generally it's occurs when you remove a method (1) for delegate (E.g.TexChanged, Click) but you not remove the reference(2) for this method in design source (Form1.Designer.cs).

```
//1.
private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//2.
this.txtBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtBox_TextChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found 4 simple steps to solve this error:

1. Visual Studio => Run as Admin
2. Project Properties => Build => Platform Target : Any Cpu
3. Build => Clean
4. Run

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue yesterday under Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 and I fixed it by restarting the Visual Studio and rebuilding the complete solution. Now the error message was gone and I was able to debug the project again.

Answer (score 1):

**4 steps to solved a problem :**

1. open your project.
2. from solution explorer select your project name Beside them icon" c#" and right click and select properties.
3. click Application > startup object: (Not set) > change to (your project name) .program.
4. run a project (F5)

**Now the project is working successfully.**

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this happen with two of my students using Visual Studio 2015 and C#.   The students created a project and named it Joe's Automotive.
The apostrophe in Joe's caused the issue.

The solution is to right click  on the project, choose properties
Under Application:   Remove the apostrophe in the Assembly name

Example:
Original Assembly name:   Joe's Automotive
Fixed Assembly name:   Joes Automotive

Save and rebuild the project and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the assembly name matches a DLL name in the same folder. For example:

- Test.exe
- Test.dll

The application will fail to launch within Visual Studio due to the Test.dll in the same folder. Changing your projects Assembly Name will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin and obj folders and re-run.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the code and create new application. When creating new app, write a name without spaces if you want to rename WindowsApplciation1 from the very beginning. Or you can name it with spaces but by selecting File-Save all... and name it how you want.

Answer (score -3):

I found any simple steps to solve this error

1- change your windows

2- install all driver on your computer

3- install Symantec Endpoint Protection Client 12.1.6318.6100 x32 or x64 bit

You can get it saftware(32 bit) from link:
(ftp://192.168.168.215/Public/Antivirus/Symantec/Symantec Endpoint Protection 
Client 12.1.6318.6100 x86.rar)

End

Answer (score -3):

I found simple steps to solve this error:(100%)

1. Change Windows
2. install good antivirus (for example Avira) **and dont disable antivirus**
3. install your driver on your computer
4. install Visual Studio
5. install your software